# Why doesn't destructuring MessageEvent via the spread operator return all properties?

Tags: javascript

In the Chrome dev console:

```
event = new MessageEvent({data: 'some data'})
MessageEvent {isTrusted: false, data: null, origin: "", lastEventId: "", source: null, …}
```

When I try the spread operator:

```
{...event}
{isTrusted: false}
```

...I only see the `isTrusted` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spread operator only copies an object's own enumerable properties, not properties found higher on the prototype chain. If you look at `event`'s own properties you'll see it just has the `isTrusted` property.

```
> Object.getOwnPropertyNames(event)
> ["isTrusted"]
```

If you look one step up on the prototype chain you'll see where some of the other properties are:

```
> Object.getOwnPropertyNames(event.__proto__)
> (7) ["data", "origin", "lastEventId", "source", "ports", "initMessageEvent", "constructor"]
```